# Unable to publish msg to GCP pubsub from AWS NodeJs Lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, aws-lambda, google-cloud-pubsub

Im trying to get a lambda function to publish a message to a gcp pubsub topic.
Im using classes in the code below hence the omission of the pubsub client initialization and "function" after the async. Theres also the inconsistency of the message argument not being used. I was just testing if it could publish send a simple msg.

From the cloudwatch logs, i can see the client initialization works - from a console log not shown - and the logging shows up to the point where it says:

> About to publish

However execution of the lambda function ends abruptly right after without any logging.

I was able to successfully publish a message with a basic implementation of the function to the same topic using the same gcp credentials. I have no idea why the catch block fails to show the error. Is there some error suppression config to be changed?
Ive set timeout to a minute, but it runs in milliseconds so thats not it. Its not in a vpc. So im out of ideas.

- Using `nodejs runtime: 14.x`
- pubsub package version:
  `"@google-cloud/pubsub": "^2.19.0"`

```
class PubSubProducer {
  /**
   * PubSubProducer constructor
   * @param {Object} config - PubSub Producer Config
   */
  constructor(config) {
    this.msg = 'Published messageId';
    console.log('Creating PubSubProducer...');
    if (!config.credentials && !process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) {
      console.log(
        'Missing PubSub credentials!  They must be provided in config.credentials or in a file ' +
          'referenced by the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable.'
      );
      throw new Error('[PubSubProducer] Missing PubSub credentials!');
    }
    const pubSubConfig = {
      projectId: config.credentials.project_id,
    };

    // If process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS exists use it, else use config.credentials.
    if (!process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) {
      // delete config.credentials.private_key_secret_name;
      pubSubConfig.credentials = config.credentials;
    }
    console.log('This is the pubsub config');
    console.log(pubSubConfig.credentials);

    console.log('This is the pubsub client instantiation');
    pubSubClient = new PubSub(pubSubConfig);
    console.log(pubSubClient);
}

 async publish(topic, message) {
    const data = JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' });
    const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);
    console.log(dataBuffer);
    let messageId;
    console.log(`Topic: ${topic}`);
    console.log('About to publish');
    try {
      messageId = await pubSubClient.topic(topic).publishMessage({
        data: dataBuffer,
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(
        `Error : failed to publish to Pub/Sub topic ${topic}.  Error was ${ex.message}`
      );
    }
    console.log(`${this.msg} ${messageId} to topic ${topic}`);
  }
}
```

So the cloudwatch logs are:

```
2022-03-24T22:07:27.675Z    5a4e4c3c-fb0c-4fa8-a955-e6d9edbc3508    INFO    This is the pubsub client instantiation
2022-03-24T22:07:27.675Z 5a4e4c3c-fb0c-4fa8-a955-e6d9edbc3508 INFO PubSub {
  getSubscriptionsStream: [Function (anonymous)],
  getSnapshotsStream: [Function (anonymous)],
  getTopicsStream: [Function (anonymous)],
  isOpen: true,
  options: {
    libName: 'gccl',
    libVersion: '2.19.0',
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub'
    ],
    projectId: 'REDACTED',
    credentials: {
      type: 'REDACTED',
      project_id: 'REDACTED',
      private_key_id: 'REDACTED',
      client_email: 'REDACTED',
      client_id: 'REDACTED',
      auth_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
      token_uri: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
      auth_provider_x509_cert_url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
      client_x509_cert_url: 'REDACTED',
      private_key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n' +
        'MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCz+LHwKnhu9wgs\n' +
        '5o+B0c8ISgphQHGJ8Qy7dhlQc8x+u98YcOMOTaJjrGB7TeKOnDynK38NXdS7bghD\n' +
        'REDACTED'
        'cUuRX1BQb25qBVhhZvXMJpy0\n' +
        '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'
    }
  },
  isEmulator: false,
  api: {},
  auth: GoogleAuth {
    checkIsGCE: undefined,
    jsonContent: {
      type: 'REDACTED',
      project_id: 'REDACTED',
      private_key_id: 'REDACTED',
      client_email: 'REDACTED',
      client_id: 'REDACTED',
      auth_uri: 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
      token_uri: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
      auth_provider_x509_cert_url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs',
      client_x509_cert_url: 'REDACTED',
      private_key: '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n' +
        'MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCz+LHwKnhu9wgs\n' +
        '5o+B0c8ISgphQHGJ8Qy7dhlQc8x+u98YcOMOTaJjrGB7TeKOnDynK38NXdS7bghD\n' +
        'REDACTED'
        'cUuRX1BQb25qBVhhZvXMJpy0\n' +
        '-----END PRIVATE KEY-----'
    },
    cachedCredential: null,
    _cachedProjectId: 'REDACTED',
    keyFilename: undefined,
    scopes: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/pubsub'
    ],
    clientOptions: undefined
  },
  projectId: 'REDACTED',
  name: 'REDACTED'
}
2022-03-24T22:07:27.676Z    5a4e4c3c-fb0c-4fa8-a955-e6d9edbc3508    INFO    <Buffer 7b 22 66 6f 6f 22 3a 22 62 61 72 22 7d>
2022-03-24T22:07:27.676Z    5a4e4c3c-fb0c-4fa8-a955-e6d9edbc3508    INFO    Topic: inbound
2022-03-24T22:07:27.676Z    5a4e4c3c-fb0c-4fa8-a955-e6d9edbc3508    INFO    About to publish
END RequestId: 5a4e4c3c-fb0c-4fa8-a955-e6d9edbc3508
```

Comment: How do you set tthe credentials in your Lambda function?

Comment: Can you show the CloudWatch logs from START to END so we see how it ends abruptly?

Comment: @NoelLlevares the stack trace is a bit long, but i updated my question with the last couple of lines

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, im using the setting it up with the credentials object, that has the private key, project_id and other relevant keys

Comment: In CloudWatch logs, what does the REPORT line say after each invocation?

Comment: @NoelLlevares REPORT RequestId: 16679950-8e49-4355-b607 Duration: 12.82 ms Billed Duration: 13 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 108 MB Init Duration: 1046.42 ms